# Unknown disk, not initialized fix data error cyclic redundancy check CRC error for hard drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, sata, recovery-partition

I tried to add my old hard drive in my PC.

1. First tried with **SATA Cable**
2. Second tried with **USB To SATA Cable**

In both of them HDD status is `not initialized` and type is `unknown`
unknown disk not initialized fix data

I tried to initial disk in disk management and receive following error:

> Disk error (cyclic redundancy check)

I tried with CMD command like following commands step by step:

```
C:\Windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.18362.1533

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: AMIRNBA9

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          238 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online          931 GB   931 GB

DISKPART> Select disk 2

Disk 2 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> create partion primary

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.18362.1533

PARTITION   - Create a partition.
VOLUME      - Create a volume.
VDISK       - Creates a virtual disk file.

DISKPART> create partition primary

DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART> Select disk 2

Disk 2 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> format
```

and give error for all type of partition:

```
DISKPART> create partition efi

DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART> create partition extended

DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART> create partition logical

DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART> create partition msr

DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART> create partition primary

DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
See the System Event Log for more information.
```

Then I checked error-log and find this :

> The device, \Device\Harddisk2\DR3, has a bad block.

Then download [WinObj](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/WinObj.zip) and read [fixed article](https://www.wintips.org/fix-event-7-disk-has-a-bad-block-at-device-harddisk/)  but my hard drive isn't `Volume` like that.

[image]

I can't find any solution for fixed this problem.

my disk attribute is :

```
attributes disk
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

DISKPART> DETAIL disk

ST310003 40NS USB Device
Disk ID: 00000000
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No
```

Use SmartTools :

```
smartctl -t short /dev/sdc
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-w10-1909] (sf-7.2-1)

Smartctl open device: /dev/sdc [USB JMicron] failed: IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH failed, Error=1167
```

Comment: _Please do not post screenshots of terminal content - copy/paste the output into a code box_. What does the System Event Log say _(use google to find the appropriate log location in Event Viewer [`eventvwr.msc`])_? Please post it and the S.M.A.R.T info within your question: Download [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download) → Run a short S.M.A.R.T test: `smartctl -t short /dev/<drive>` → Wait 61s → Get S.M.A.R.T info: `smartctl -a /dev/<drive>`, ensuring it lists the short test as completed, and please post the output of the info within a code box in your question.

Comment: @JW0914 Thank you. I tried by smartmontools, find disk use by `smartctl --scan` and run with error following command `smartctl -t short /dev/sdc` and recive error : `failed: IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH failed, Error=1167`

Comment: CRC errors typically refer to transfer errors, and not media errors.  I.E. the problem is with the SATA cable or connectors, rather than the drive.

Comment: Which disk? How is it connected? What motherboard?

Comment: @harrymc I have **Segate  1TB sata HDD** , I tried use this hard on 2 PC with SATA cable and tried on Laptop with **Convertor SATA to USB** both of model no problem with other HDD.

Comment: The series model number of the disk would help. But are you sure that the disk is healthy?

Comment: @Amirhossein To verify, when you tested the drive on the two PCs, the SATA cable and motherboard connector used worked fine with other drives? If so, and  due to `smartctl` being unable to even access the drive, it's likely the drive has critical hardware damage if you've ruled out the SATA cable and motherboard connector. As a last ditch effort, you could try a bad block DOS marker program _(per the error log message)_, but it'll take a day or so to run on a 1TB HDD _(I don't recall the names of such software, but do know they're included within Hiren's BootCD)_.

Comment: Connect the drive directly to the PC before running `smartctl` so as to rule out problems with your USB-SATA adapter.